# Generate csv based on data of different type

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to generate a csv file based on a range of pieces of data: int, float, string, list of strings, list of float:

```
temp = 15.3
id = '98'
tags = ['b34s', '7eo9', '7w49']
hum = 1.89
x_data = [32,87,87,742,342,7.2,992,...]
y_data = [65.3,89.7,458.8,589,529,8789,489,...]
```

The x_data and y_data lists might have thousands of elements. I would like the generated file to look as follows:

```
|temp|id|tags|hum.|x_data|y_data|
|15.3|98|b34s|1.89|    32|  65.3|
|    |  |7eo9|    |    87|  89.7|
|    |  |7w49|    |    87| 458.8|
|    |  |    |    |   742|   589|
|    |  |    |    |   342|   529|
|    |  |    |    |   7.2|  8789|
|    |  |    |    |   992|   489|
|    |  |    |    |   ...|   ...|
```

As you can see, the csv consists of columns. Some columns only contain one piece of data, some more. I tried to achieve this by using the csv library. However, the writerow method seems inappropriate due to the different types of data to be stored. I tried using pandas, but I am having trouble adding columns of different length. Either the column ends up being populated by one value I provide (only the first row should be, in this case), or the remaining rows get populated by NaN.

Could you please suggest how to tackle that problem?

Comment: You can add spaces in the place of null values. can't you?

Comment: It doesn't really make sens to store your data in such a way. The fact that the types are different across your lists shoudn't be a problem, you just need them to be of the same length.

Comment: That is an unusual setup of a data file as usually most cells are populated especially indicator fields like *id*. Curious how this file will be used? How do *xdata* and *ydata* relate? Do they have same length and are they multiples of the length of *tags*? Pandas can fill or leave as NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the itertools library if everything you have is an iterable.

There is a function izip_longest in python 2.7 or zip_longest in python 3.x. This function takes iterables and returns a generator that will keep going until the last value in the longest iterable is exhausted. You can find the documentation [here for itertools in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

This function has a `fillvalue` parameter that let's you choose exactly what value to fill the empty ones with.

You can pass the returned generator directly to to the `csv.writerows` function.

```
>>> # assuming your values are iterables
>>> temp = [15.3]
>>> id = ['98']
>>> tags = ['b34s', '7eo9', '7w49']
>>> hum = [1.89]
>>> x_data = [32,87,87,742,342,7.2,992]
>>> y_data = [65.3,89.7,458.8,589,529,8789,489]

>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [zipped for zipped in izip_longest(temp, id, tags, hum, x_data, y_data)]
[(15.3, '98', 'b34s', 1.89, 32, 65.3),
 (None, None, '7eo9', None, 87, 89.7),
 (None, None, '7w49', None, 87, 458.8),
 (None, None, None, None, 742, 589),
 (None, None, None, None, 342, 529),
 (None, None, None, None, 7.2, 8789),
 (None, None, None, None, 992, 489)
]
>>> [zipped for zipped in izip_longest(temp, id, tags, hum, x_data, y_data, fillvalue='')]
[(15.3, '98', 'b34s', 1.89, 32, 65.3),
 ('', '', '7eo9', '', 87, 89.7),
 ('', '', '7w49', '', 87, 458.8),
 ('', '', '', '', 742, 589),
 ('', '', '', '', 342, 529),
 ('', '', '', '', 7.2, 8789),
 ('', '', '', '', 992, 489)
]
```